# Problem books in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I'm studying Ordinary differential equations right now in the level of [Hartman's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898715105).

I've never seen problem books in ODE in this level even if you consider it without solutions.

I would like to know if one of you know any problem book in ODE in this level?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know the level of Hartman's book. Isn't there a Schaum's Outline for ODE? Is it suitable?

Comment: @GerryMyerson no, because ODE in Schaum's outline is just solve some differential equations. I'm asking about prove the uniqueness and domain of the solutions, Kineser theorem, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of another book like this one.

I think you can do several things, like finding books with the main themes, for example:

- Example 1: About Exponential Dichotomy of Linear Autonomous Differential Equations, Mircea Reghis
- Example 2: Perturbation Methods for Differential Equations, Bhimsen Shivamoggi
- Example 3: Countable Systems of Differential Equations by A. M. Samoilenko, Yu. V. Teplinskii
- Another Suggestion: Review the extensive list of references in his book and see other books on the main themes that he used, including the referenced papers

Comment: OP asked about *problem* books. Are these problem books?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That is precisely my point, there are none. His only option is to get books in the hopes of having examples, problems, maybe some solutions. In fact, the book you cite does not have the types of problems that are useful with the Hartman book. Regards

Comment: +1 Good effort...Maybe a publisher will see this post, and decide it might be worth publishing such a problem book! ;-)

Comment: @Amzoti please write this book :)